# Cache javascript value in Blazor Server when use component and is rendered from same page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a component, re-used, that converts date time saved in database to client's date. As 3rd party library to Blazor Server, I use Radzen, latest version.

I have the interface `IDateTimeConverter`:

```
public interface IDateTimeConverter
{
   string ToClientDateAndTime(DateTimeOffset? date, int timezoneOffset);
}
```

and the implementation

```
public string ToClientDateAndTime(DateTimeOffset? date, int timezoneOffset)
{
            if (date == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            var time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-timezoneOffset);
            var localTime = date.Value.ToOffset(time);
            return localTime.ToString("dd/MM/yy:HH:mm");
}
```

and my component called `LocalTime`, code behind:

```
[Inject] private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
[Inject] private IDateTimeConverter TimeConverter { get; set; }
[Parameter] public DateTime Date { get; set; }

private CancellationToken _token;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
            base.OnInitialized();
            _token = new CancellationTokenSource().Token;
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
         if (firstRender)
         {
                _clientOffset = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("getclienttimezone", _cancellationToken);
                StateHasChanged();
         }
}
```

and in UI

```
<p>@TimeConverter.ToClientDateAndTime(Date, _clientOffset)</p>
```

I have several pages that re-use above component:

```
@foreach(var myModel in ModelItems)
{
   <p><LocalTime Date="@myModel.CreatedOn" /></p>
   ...
   ...
   <p><LocalTime Date="@myModel.UpdatedOn" /></p>
   ...
   ...
   <p><LocalTime Date="@myModel.DeletedOn" /></p>
}
```

There's a way somehow for LocalTime to do not call javascript for each row and keep somehow same value if is from same request ? How can improve when I have 100 rows per page to avoid 100 calls of javascript ?

I have also other main pages that re-use `LocalTime` component.

Comment: Scoped services in Blazor Server are shared across a single request. Couldn't you save the value in a scoped service and then only call the javascript to get the offset if it hasn't already been set?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a ultra clean way to this because you have to render the first page/component before you can access the browser code to get the offset.  But here's a pattern to apply.  I'm not sure I've got the local time logic right, but you can fix that.

A Scoped DI Service.

```
public class TimeService
{
    public TimeSpan TimeZoneOffset { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler? TimeZoneChanged;

    public bool IsSet { get; private set; }

    public void SetOffsetFromBrowsetOffset(int minutes)
    {
        IsSet = true;
        TimeZoneOffset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-minutes);
        TimeZoneChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public DateTimeOffset GetBrowserLocalTime(DateTimeOffset date)
        => date.ToOffset(TimeZoneOffset);
}
```

Registered:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<TimeService>();
```

site.js registered in *_Layout.html**

```
window.blazr_GetBrowserTimeZoneOffset = function () {
    return new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
}
```

Two alternative ways to implement.

##### Method 1

```cs
public class BrowserTimeComponent : IComponent, IHandleAfterRender
{
    [Parameter] public EventCallback NeedToRender { get; set; }
    [Inject] private IJSRuntime _js { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] private TimeService _timeService { get; set; } = default!;

    private bool _hasRendered;
    private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
    private RenderFragment _renderFragment;
    private bool _renderPending;

    public BrowserTimeComponent()
    {
        _renderFragment = (builder) =>
        {
            _renderPending = false;
        };
    }

    public void Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
        => _renderHandle = renderHandle;

    public async Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        if (!_hasRendered)
        {
            var offset = await _js.InvokeAsync<int>("blazr_GetBrowserTimeZoneOffset");
            this._timeService.SetOffsetFromBrowsetOffset(offset);
            _hasRendered = true;
            await NeedToRender.InvokeAsync();
        }
    }

    public Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (_renderPending)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        _renderPending = true;
        _renderHandle.Render(_renderFragment);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

With this demo implementation:

```cs
@inject TimeService TimeService

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>


<BrowserTimeComponent NeedToRender=this.Render />

<div>
    BrowserTime @this.TimeService.GetBrowserLocalTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
</div>


@code {
    private void Render()
            => this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

##### Method 1

Component:

```cs
public class TimeComponent : IComponent, IHandleAfterRender, IDisposable
{
    [Inject] private IJSRuntime _js { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] private TimeService _timeService { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
    private RenderFragment _renderFragment;
    private bool _isInitialized;
    private bool _renderPending;

    public TimeComponent()
    {
        _renderFragment = (builder) =>
        {
            _renderPending = false;

            // Set the renderfragment based on TimeService state
            if (_timeService.IsSet)
                builder.AddContent(0, this.ChildContent ?? this.NoContentRenderComponent);
            else
                RenderComponent(builder);
        };
    }

    public void Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
        => _renderHandle = renderHandle;

    public async Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        if (!_timeService.IsSet)
        {
            var offset = await _js.InvokeAsync<int>("blazr_GetBrowserTimeZoneOffset");
            this._timeService.SetOffsetFromBrowsetOffset(offset);
        }
    }

    private void RenderComponent(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        => builder.AddContent(0, "Loading Browser Time...");

    private void NoContentRenderComponent(RenderTreeBuilder builder) { }

    public Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Set the underlying parameters
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        // Register event handler for TimeZone Change
        if (!_isInitialized)
            _timeService.TimeZoneChanged += OnTimeZoneChange;

        // Render the component
        _renderHandle.Render(_renderFragment);

        _isInitialized = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async void OnTimeZoneChange(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => await _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);

    private void StateHasChanged()
    {
        if (_renderPending)
            return;

        _renderPending = true;
        _renderHandle.Render(_renderFragment);
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => _timeService.TimeZoneChanged += OnTimeZoneChange;
}
```

With this demo implementation:

```cs
@inject TimeService TimeService

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<TimeComponent>
    BrowserTime @this.TimeService.GetBrowserLocalTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
</TimeComponent>
```